# Garbage chars in Grafana queries

Tags: grafana

I was playing with Grafana (V 8.1) and found a annoying bug. Its intermittently inserting the garbage chars in between the queries and its very hard to remove those in lengthy queries. Even if you are able to do it it will come again after few refresh. I tried both chrome and edge but issue is same.
Is there any workaround or fix for this annoying issue? I tried plain notepad and notepad++ as well but in vain.

Error is

```
"invalid parameter \"query\": 1:32: parse error: unexpected character inside braces: '\\ufeff'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix: upgrade your old 8.1 Grafana to newer version (current latest is 10.x), where this issue is fixed.

Comment: Why they haven't fixed this small bug on other versions? These versions are simply no usable.

Comment: @Muditbhaintwal why they even introduce a bugs :-D? How much will cost to fix any issue in all released Grafana versions? I think you don't understand Grafana Life Cycle and Release policy. Your 8.1 is so old, that vendor won't help you even if you have paid Grafana support, because it is EOL. There are no security releases for 8.x, so why you expect bug fixes for minor issue?